# How can I get an inner class's outer class's this in Java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have two classes, `Outer` and `Inner`, and a method in `Outer` that takes an `Inner`. It needs to validate that this `Inner` is one of its own, and not an `Inner` that belongs to another instance. What I'd like to do is essentially `innerInstance.outer.this`, but there doesn't seem to be a keyword for that. My only other idea is a `getOuterThis()` method on `Inner`, but I'd rather not have to resort to that.

Here's the general skeleton of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public class Outer {

    public Inner getInner() { ... }

    public void useInner(Inner inner) {
        // Validate here
    }

    public class Inner {
        // Can I avoid this?
        public Outer getOuterThis() {
            return Outer.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EJP The Eclipse compiler didn't like it. And this is a different question from the duplicate you linked. This is how to do it from the outer class without adding a method to the inner class. The answer there was clearly just Outer.this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way to get the `Outer.this` reference except by explicitly exposing it like you're doing. However, you can probably avoid this altogether by having the inner class do the validation:

```
public class Outer {

    public Inner getInner() { ... }

    public void useInner(Inner inner) {
        // Validate
        inner.validateOuterInstance(this);
    }

    public class Inner {
        public void validateOuterInstance(Outer outer) {
            if (Outer.this != outer) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Wrong outer instance");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need an instance to call the validate method on. fyi...

Comment: @lhasadad - Yes, you're right. It looks like David Ehrmann fixed it for me.